# Contador de visualizações

Tags: php

Estou fazendo uma aplicação em PHP e gostaria de fazer um contador para manter registro de cada visualização que as páginas da aplicação tiverem e armazenar em um banco de dados, porém não tenho muita noção de como fazer isso.

Comment: sua aplicação terá conexão com banco de dados? Se sim, qual?

Comment: [Edite](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/273679/edit) sua pergunta e coloque o código que já tentou!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Na tabela onde ficam guardadas as informações dessa página, coloca um campo *int* para armazenar o número de visualizações.

Sempre que a página for acessada, pega o valor atual do campo e soma +1, aí então faz o *update* na tabela para atualizar o contador.

Answer (score -1):

Cria um banco de dados e toda vez que alguém acessa sua pagina você aumenta um registro em alguma tabela no banco, ou então você faça num arquivo local e sempre verificar ou o banco ou o arquivo quando a pagina é carregada.